# Brokers are not available

Tags: apache-kafka

To /etc/kafka/server.properties the broker is configured using:

```
############################# Server Basics #############################
# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0
############################# Socket Server Settings #############################
# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://<MY_HOST_NAME>:9092,SASL_SSL://<MY_HOST_NAME>:9093
```

To check the brokers I run:

```
/opt/confluent-kafka/v5.5.0/bin/zookeeper-shell localhost:2181 ls /brokers/ids
```

Which returns:

```
Connecting to localhost:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[]
```

So, it seems that the brokers are not running. As kafka server.properties(above) contains:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://<MY_HOST_NAME>:9092,SASL_SSL://<MY_HOST_NAME>:9093
```

shouldn't the broker be available ?

My understanding is `listeners=PLAINTEXT://<MY_HOST_NAME>:9092,SASL_SSL://<MY_HOST_NAME>:9093` is the config that allows the brokers to be accessible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the connection is within the same host (*no advertised listeners nor external clients involved here*).
Change the listeners property to make the broker listen to all interfaces:

**`listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,SASL_SSL://0.0.0.0:9093`**

If you set your `<hostname>` as the listener, `localhost` won't be recognized as a valid binding point: there's no registered "`localhost`" listener, just the one specified on your config, `<hostname>`.

By setting `0.0.0.0` as listener, **the broker will bind to all interfaces**, hence accepting `localhost` as a valid endpoint. You could find more info regarding this [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/).